# Moving PHP files from one server to the other

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, php

I am working on a project (based on PHP, HTML and CSS) which is live on a Windows server. During development, we work inside a dev folder on the same server. So developers' access the link to the project would be "www.myproject.com/dev" whereas the actual link to the live version would be "www.myproject.com".

Since the project has now gone live, we are planning to move our development files to another linux server running CentOS 6 which would be "dev.myproject.com". I have copied all my files to this new server. However, the pages do not load up fine.

The HTML part of the project, is not being able to display data that has been retrieved from the database by the php file. When I display the PHP retrieved information using the echo command it is correct. So I know that PHP is working fine. However, I am not sure as to why HTML cannot display this information.

Is this something to do with the way PHP and Apache have been configured on the new server? I am new to Linux. Can you please help me as to which part of the config files should I edit to make it work fine?

Comment: Exactly what is the problem you are having?

Answer (score 1):

If your server is using PHP5 then add this in httpd.conf on your server

```
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm
```

If it's not PHP5 then use

```
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```